# Completely Uninstall Steam and ALL steam games

Tags: 14.04, steam

Will `sudo apt-get purge steam` completely remove steam and **all** the games installed with it?

Is there anything else that I have to remove or run to achieve this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That will only remove the steam installer. Steam itself, and all games installed through it, are not part of the packaging system.

You will also need to delete the `~/.local/share/Steam/` folder and its contents, to fully remove Steam and its games from your system. If you chose to install any games in alternate directories not under `~/.local/share/Steam/`, you will also need to remove them as well.

Comment: what if i have installed some of the games on a different location?  Just remove that directory?

Comment: @AFwcxx, yes, you'll have to delete those directories as well.

Comment: There is also a `~/.steam` directory to remove. It contains EULA and some symlinks. Delete that too.

Comment: I only had `steam-launcher` installed.